# R - set names of nested list elements according to values in another nested list

Tags: r

Let's say that we have two nested lists with the equal number of levels:

```
list1 <- list(list("a", "b"),
              list("c", "d"))

list2 <- list(list("e", "f"),
              list("g", "h"))
```

Now I want to set the names of the elements of the ***sublist*** of `list1` according to the values of `list2`. The desired output would be equivalent to using this:

```
list1 <- list(list(e = "a", 
                   f = "b"),
              list(g = "c", 
                   h = "d"))
```

However, I need a way to not do it manually and to instead pull the values from `list2` and assign them as names to the appropriate list level of `list1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Base R:** Use `setNames()` within `lapply()`:

```
list1 <- lapply(
  seq_along(list1),
  \(i) setNames(list1[[i]], list2[[i]])
)
```

**tidyverse:** Use `purrr::map2()` to loop over both lists simultaneously:

```
library(purrr)

list1 <- map2(list1, list2, set_names)
```

Output in both cases:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$e
[1] "a"

[[1]]$f
[1] "b"


[[2]]
[[2]]$g
[1] "c"

[[2]]$h
[1] "d"
```

Comment: So in `tidyverse` it would be `list1 <- imap(seq_along(list1), ~set_names(list1[[.y]], list2[[.y]]))`. Thanks, it works!

Comment: Yup. You could also do `map2(list1, list2, set_names)` - I’ll add that to my answer.

Comment: How would you do it if lists have not two, but three levels? `list1 <- list(list(list("a", "b"), list("c", "d")), list(list("e", "f"), list("g", "h")))` and `list2 <- list(list(list("i", "j"), list("k", "l")), list(list("m", "n"), list("o", "p")))` It seems that `map2` doesn't work in that case. What works is `map2(list1[[1]], list2[[1]], set_names)` and `map2(list1[[2]], list2[[2]], set_names)` - but I need to do it jointly

Comment: Nvm, the way to do it is by nesting `map2` within `map2`